# SFDX - CI - Named Credentials and environments

Tags: salesforcedx, namedcredentials, continuous-integration, cicd, environment

We have a repository with metadata in source format, and we use sfdx and ci job to deploy, some metadata (Named Credentials for this instance) contains some values that are env/org dependant.

For the example above, we need to replace `endpoint`, `username`, and `password` depending on the env/org we are deploying to with CI job.

Is there anything like `dotenv` for PHP to do that?

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<NamedCredential xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <allowMergeFieldsInBody>true</allowMergeFieldsInBody>
    <allowMergeFieldsInHeader>false</allowMergeFieldsInHeader>
    <endpoint>https://login.microsoftonline.com/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/oauth2/token</endpoint>
    <generateAuthorizationHeader>false</generateAuthorizationHeader>
    <label>AZURE_ActiveDirectory</label>
    <principalType>NamedUser</principalType>
    <protocol>Password</protocol>
    <username>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</username>
    <password>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</password>
</NamedCredential>
```

Comment: Don't know about any tool to do this. But I'd remove the named credentials from VCS as it is contains secrets and put them in .gitignore. Instead develop some script to create the named credentials in the target org (probably using SOAP API).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a workaround, i use .env files to store environement variables and i use a GitHub Workflow to substitute values in the metadata files, passwords/usernames/and tokens are stored as GitHub secrets and substituted also during deployment like env variables.